# restoring database sql server

Tags: sql-server, database, restore

I have a probleme while restoring my database from a .bak file. If I use sql query line I'll find the database but with no table in it, and if I use restoring wizard with the same file and the default configuration i'll get my database and my tables. I think that I'm missing something in this query:

first query

```
RESTORE DATABASE ColisageTest
      FROM  DISK = 'e:\colisageTest.bak'
```

second query

```
RESTORE DATABASE ColisageTest
  FROM  DISK = 'e:\colisageTest.bak'
  WITH REPLACE,
 MOVE 'ColisageTest' TO 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.COLISAGE\MSSQL\DATA\ColisageTest.mdf',
 MOVE 'ColisageTest_log' TO 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.COLISAGE\MSSQL\DATA\ColisageTest_log.ldf'
GO
```

third query

```
RESTORE DATABASE ColisageTest
  FROM  DISK = 'e:\colisageTest.bak'
  with RECOVERY;
GO
```

No one of them is working all of them it just restore my database but no tables

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the database is not empty on tables?
One way to test this is to make another .bak file (that you know have tables) and try to restore it for validation.

No problem with empty tables I'm saying you might have an empty database, ie there is no table there at all.

Comment: this will probably be flag as being a comment, not an answer.

Comment: yes the table is empty there is any problem with empty tables ?

Comment: I found that if I add to my query `with file=1;`  it will work fine but the number one is the count of how many time you did a backup so I need to find a solution to get how many time i did a backup, all that i know now is  that the count of this query `RESTORE HEADERONLY
FROM DISK = N'e:\colisageTest.bak` gives me the exact int to use it as argument for `with file=1;` but I don't know how to transmit the result form a query to an other